# PHP Cron job on plesk server, can't load mssql.so

Tags: php, cron, plesk

I've set up my first cron on a new server running plesk. The script can't access the database and just throws this error:

*PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mssql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mssql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0*

I used the following settings to run the cron job:

`php /path/to/my/script.php`

And also tried:

`/usr/bin/php /path/to/my/script.php`

Not a problem in the script, I have tested manually.

Comment: Are the access rights ok for access to that file when the cron job is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server likely doesn't have the mssql module installed.

```
zipp@zeratul:~$ sudo apt-cache search php5 mssql
php5-sybase - Sybase / MS SQL Server module for php5
```

Comment: I mis-read the warning message, I thought it was talking about MySQL, not MSSQL. Yes, you're right it's not installed, thanks for your help. BA.